Server failing to load resource and GET error being 404 (Not Found)
I have been trying to get my server using NodeJS, ExpressJS and SocketIO to work on my application so that the database can operate correctly but I keep getting these errors:
:5500/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=PDfbnR8:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

manager.js:108 
        
        
       GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=PDfboDf 404 (Not Found)

Here's my server side code:
let connections = [];
let initialRun = [];

// Middleware
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3"); // Database package
const db = new sqlite3.Database("Highscores.db");
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require("express"); // Acting as client
const app = express();
const socket = require("socket.io");
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static("Public"));  // Attaches my client-side files to the program
// ----------------

// Server API
const PORT = 3000;
var server = app.listen(PORT, function(){   // Displays that the server is running after checking for 3 secs
    console.log("CORS-enabled web server is listening on port 3000");
});
var io = socket(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});
io.on("connection", connected); // Listens for a connection
// ---------------------

Here's my client side code:
let socket = io.connect({
    withCredentials: true,

    transportOptions: {
        polling: {
            extraHeaders: {
                "my-custom-header": "abcd"
            }
        }
    }
});;    // Provides the ability for a socket connection to occur

Having looked into it further myself, I have found that the main error code comes out as this when you press on the file link on DevTools
Cannot GET /socket.io/

I've googled all over the place looking at ways to fix it and can't seem to find a single one. Port 3000 works for both server and client now after some reshuffle but the server-side database still isn't working properly.
Any help would be much appreciated! Many Thanks :D

Not necessarily your problem but CORS origins should not include paths; just the scheme, host and port

new Server(80, ...  that's port 80 but your client is trying to connect to port 5500

"apparently port 3000 is already in use"... yes, by your Express server

Hi Phil! Thanks for the help! I have managed to alter my code so that both the client and server are running on port 3000, but I am still getting the same error, any ideas? Many thanks :D

Please [edit] your question with the code you're using now. Your client side code is still trying to hit port 5500

Hi Phil, thanks, the code has been updated with the new code :D

Updated the question with things I've found in hope of more help trying to fix this, thank you!
